# Проблема с libgdx на Android

Tags: android, opengl, libgdx

Сначала все работало нормально, рендерился 3d и т.д. но потом по неизвестным причинам стали ловить ошибку:

```
E/linker﹕ load_library(linker.cpp:757): library "/system/lib/libgsl.so" not found
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 19264
```

Откатывались на предыдущие варианты кода, пытались запускать сэмплы - не работает. Подскажите, что теперь делать?

Comment: в каталоге libs в папках armeabi / armeabi-v7a / x86  в каждой из них есть libgsl.so ? возможно вы использовали другой эмулятор раньше ?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Да понятный вопрос, у него просто проекты не видят нативные библиотеки libgdx. Надо проверять правильность подключения просто. Я бы советовал просто по инструкции опять libgdx с 0 импортировать в проект.